# Правильно ли расставлены запятые 2

Tags: пунктуация

Запятая после "что" вызывает сомнение. Стоит она или нет?

Пап, если что, я экономлю зарядку, так что буду сидеть в авиарежиме.

Answer (score 2):

Это запись устной речи, неполное придаточное предложение, запятая нужна:

Пап, если что (будет нужно), (то) я экономлю зарядку, так что буду сидеть в авиарежиме.

Answer (score 1):

Это разговорная конструкция, поэтому бесспорных рекомендаций может и не быть, трактовка грамматики затруднена.
Но вообще-то "если что" здесь скорее всего вводные слова, поэтому обособлять необходимо.

А если не вводное, то что?

Answer (score 1):

Знак препинания здесь нужен, поскольку в простое предложение слова здесь не укладываются, однако в случае запятой создаётся ложное впечатление, что зарядку экономят в некоторых случаях (если что-то случается, я экономлю), в то время как видимый смысл иной (не беспокойся, если сразу не сможешь связаться). Логичнее предположить недоговоренное в другой форме и поставить *двоеточие*:

> Пап, если что (=если у тебя в планах со мной связаться, скажу тебе вот
>   что)**:** я экономлю зарядку, так что буду сидеть в авиарежиме.